# iPhone XS automatically shuts down once plugged to charger

Tags: iphone, charging, power

Recently I replaced my iPhone X's battery, and it was working fine  for at least one week. Here is weird problem: when I plugged it to charger it start charging like normal, once screen goes dim & phone goes to auto lock, within one minute it auto shuts down & won’t charge, If I press power button, it won’t power on, unplugged and plugged again, no effect, normally with plugged to charger iPhone power turns on , but this doesn't happen in my case.

Now if I unplugged from the charger for 5 seconds, the iPhone auto turns on & I don't even need to press the power button. Weird thing is if I plug it into the charger and let then iPhone screen stay on, it charges like normal. iPhone battery works fine & it never goes auto off while using phone.

I'm not sure where to start to troubleshoot the problem, as I already destroyed my old original battery, While trying to change original protection board of battery, I broke original battery flex cable, so I don’t have any other battery which I can try to check to see if that it is a faulty battery or iPhone motherboard, or it might be charging board. iPhone can connect to PC with no issue and as i I said its charging battery with no problem if phone screen is on.

What I am doing is set auto lock to never & set the brightness to zero, so I can charge my iPhone. Once it reaches 100% I reset to auto lock & increases brightness to normal, but this is not the solution.

I am wondering if anybody knows what is happening, and has anyone else faced a similar problem?

Any help shall be highly appreciated